# Xetex stopped working after update to Mojave

Tags: xetex, texshop, macos

I have a document that uses Xetex that compiled perfectly fine before I updated my OS to Mojave, but now won't compile at all. I've created this simple document in Texshop (v4.24):

```
%!TEX TS-program = latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 TESTING
\end{document}
```

When I typeset it, the output starts with:

> This is /Library/TeX/texbin/simpdftex, Version 20070809
>   /Library/TeX/texbin/latex test.tex
>   This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=latex)
>   restricted \write18 enabled.
>   entering extended mode

...and it compiles without problems. However, if I change the first line to

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
```

(as in the much longer document I'm actually trying to compile), I get this:

> This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (TeX Live 2011/Fink)
>   restricted \write18 enabled.
>   (Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)

The log from when I compiled a file before Mojave says:

> This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (TeX Live 2011/Fink)   >(format=xelatex 2013.12.27)
>   21 JAN 2019 21:14
>   entering extended mode
>   restricted \write18 enabled.

...and then proceeds to run normally. These differences seem suspicious:

- the latex log mentions Tex Live 2018, which makes sense because I updated MacTex in the course of troubleshooting (2018 is now the default installation), but the xetex logs refer to Tex Live 2011
- the log for the successful xetex compilation refers to format=xelatex 2013.12.27, but the log for the unsuccessful complation does not.

I've tried *sudo fmtutil-sys --all* and *fmtutil --all*, but they didn't make any difference.

Can anyone help??

Comment: Your xetex is from (TeX Live 2011/Fink) so there seems to be a PATH problem. How did you install TeX Live 2018? Was it via MacTeX? What is the PATH variable as shown in Terminal? Use `echo $PATH` in Terminal to get it.

Comment: @Herb Yes, I installed TeX Live 2018 via MacTeX. At least I assume that's where it came from, seeing as I updated MacTeX the other day. Here's my PATH:   /Applications/anaconda/envs/py36/bin:/Applications/anaconda/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/Applications/anaconda/envs/py36/bin:/Applications/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/X11/bin

Comment: Please run `which XeTeX` to se where you are picking up the version from Fink.

Comment: Wow. It turned out that xetex was getting picked up from /sw/bin/xetex. I just prepended /Library/TeX/texbin to the PATH and now everything works perfectly. I have no idea how things got into this state, but my problem is solved. Thank you so much for taking the time to help!